# Itemization in textbox with auto complete box (example, yahoo, hotmail email, TO fields) ASP.NET + jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, tags

I want to create Itemization in textbox to get email name with id like hotmail and yahoo  to fields

[image]

I know how to work with jQuery auto complete box, the only problem is how could I get Itemization in textbox, for example "MAYA" with blue rectangle with "x". After selecting one item from auto-complete textbox I want to access name and id from c# code-behind.